# Script to copy a file into another with changed values each time

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting

File1 has some content and suppose it is :

```
as 1
df 1
qw 1
er 1
ty 1
```

Now I need to add File1 appended into File2 60 times with each time the number incremented by 1 every time.

Comment: Maybe you need to give an example of what output you expect. Cut File1 down to three lines, and do six times instead of sixty.

Comment: Post the sample output

Answer (score 0):

If there are no `1`s in File1 other than those in the second column,

```
for i in {1..60}
do
        sed "s/1/$i/" File1
done > File2
```

`{num,num}` is a bash feature and might not work in other shells.

Note that, since the above does not use the `-i` option to `sed`,
File1 is not modified.

Comment: Wouldnt this replace the 1 the first time and then for the next iteration there would not be a 1 to replace instead it would have been replaced already right?

Comment: I was trying this as i needed to replace first with i and second with i+40:
for i in {1..5}; do
j=$i+40;
sed -i -e 's/first/\"${i}\"/g' a;
sed -i -e 's/second/\"${j}\"/g' a;
cat a >> b;
done

Comment: @friend It's writing the output to a new file, so the original file still has `1` in it. You can rename `File2` to `File1` when it's all done.